# What is the Android equivalent of this iOS parse statement , userQuery.includeKey("favoriteHouses.landlord" ?)

Tags: android, ios, swift, parse-platform

I am converting an iOS app to Android. The app is using Parse as backend.
I have stuck at this particular line (nested pointer, if I am correct) :

```
 userQuery.includeKey("favoriteHouses.landlord")
```

Now I do not know how to convert this to Android :

```
parseQuery.include("favoriteHouses.landlord");
```

The above conversion does not yield any results.

Actually, I am able to get the array of pointers. But I also want to retrieve the rows of user table which exists in a field called landlord in another table. 
Here is the case :I have two tables: One is "House" and other is "User" . A user can mark houses favorite. So the favorite marked houses are stored as array of pointers in the user table.These pointers point to the houses in the house table. In the house table, there is pointer type field called landlord which contains the object id of user and is of pointer type. So, while fetching those fav houses I also want the user's by using that landlord pointer which points back to the user table.

And the whole code that I am translating to android is :

```
// A query which will return the internal array of the object received by the objectQuery
class PFArrayQuery: PFQuery {

var objectQuery: PFQuery
var returnsKey: String

init(className: String, objectQuery: PFQuery, returnsKey: String) {
    self.objectQuery = objectQuery
    self.returnsKey = returnsKey
    super.init(className: className)
}

override func findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(block: PFQueryArrayResultBlock?) {
    objectQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (result: PFObject?, error: NSError?) in
        if let error = error {
            block?(nil, error)
        } else if let array = result?[self.returnsKey] as? [PFObject] {
            block?(array, nil)
        } else {
            block?([], nil)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now the above class is used like this :

```
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let emptyQuery = PFQuery()
    guard let user = User.currentUser(),
      userQuery = User.query() else {
        return emptyQuery
    }
    let query = PFArrayQuery(className: "House", objectQuery: userQuery,
                             returnsKey: "favoriteHouses")
    userQuery.includeKey("favoriteHouses")
// this is the line which I am unable to translate.
    **userQuery.includeKey("favoriteHouses.landlord")**
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: user.objectId ?? "")
    return query
}
```

And now my translated code is :

```
ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("House");

    parseQuery.include("favoriteHouses");
    parseQuery.include("favoriteHouses.landlord");
    parseQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
```

I have also explained my situation here on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739605/unable-to-fetch-desired-records-using-parsequery-with-pointer-field-in-android) page :

Please correct me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use "public void getFirstInBackground(GetCallback<T> callback)" ?

Comment: No. I use findInBackground with callback

Comment: no exception, no result? include do not effect the results size

Comment: It has no effect to the result.

Comment: So you just get a ParseObject pointer of "favoriteHouses"? And use this ParseObject.isDataAvailable() get false? I have use multi include, and 2 level include(a.b) for a long time. All work as my expectation.

Comment: Actually, I am able to get that array of pointers. But I also want to retrieve the rows of user table which exists in a field called landlord in another table.
I have two tables: One is "House" and other is "User" . A user can mark houses favorite. So the favorited marked houses are stored as array of pointers in the user table. In the house table, there is pointer type field called landlord which contains the object id of user. So, while fetching those houses I also want the user's by using that landlord pointer which points back to the user table. You know what I mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114295/discussion-between-intellignt-idiot-and-chuntinglin).