# Unable to fetch desired records using ParseQuery with Pointer field in Android

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I am using Parse in my app. I have two tables:

1. User table
2. House table

Now, Users can create houses which are stored in the `House` table. Other users can search and mark houses as their Favorites.

Now favorite houses are saved in the `user` table as Array of pointers in field named `favoriteHouses` like this :

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"House","objectId":"irwlfQ2Ufz"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"House","objectId":"fNc1ASNXQC"},
```

This fav house array is saved in `User`'s table.

Now I can get the list of fav houses by accessing the array of pointers. I am able to do this. But I also need the `User`'s Object with each fav house. So that I know whose house is this and can show the name of the house owner.

For this, in the `house` table, there is a pointer type field named `landlord` which contains the `ObjectId` of User.

Now using this pointer I want to get the user object with the fav house.

I am doing like this :

```
ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("House");
parseQuery.include("favoriteHouses");
parseQuery.include("favoriteHouses.landlord");
```

Does the above dot operator works in Android ? It does not affect the results, with the above query I can only get the list of all the fav houses. But I also want the user object from the `user` table of the `house` owner.

Now what else do I need to add to the query so that I can get the favorite houses as well as the user object of the person who created this house attached to it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add  to house anew prop "createdBy" of type ptr to _User.  Include both array ptr A ND the new ptr in the query

Comment: House table already has a pointer to user table. Its name is "landlord"

Comment: multiple includes are legal but their targets may need to be pointed to by properties ALL IN ONE CLASS.   https://www.parse.com/questions/include-more-than-one-in-rest-api   you have 2 diff classes holding ptrs and in one query .. may not be legal